# Updating MetaData on Connected account fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using stripe connect(**destination payment**) with the help of stripe.net library from Jaymedavis.

The problem that I am facing is that I am not able to retrieve the destination payment ID to update the metadata in the connected account. The following line returns a null preventing me from updating meta data on the connected account. But the strange thing is that when I log in to the dashboard the destination payment ID exists. I am not sure why I am not able to retreive it in code.

Is the charge creation asynchronous?. I am not sure. Stripe's connect documentation does not help either. The following line returns a null. My code is down below. Seeking help.

`String deschargeID = result.Transfer.DestinationPayment;`

Here is the code that I am using

```
 var service = new StripeChargeService(ZambreroSecretKey);
 var result = (Stripe.StripeCharge) null;
 try {

  result = service.Create(newCharge);

  if (result.Paid) {

   //get the chargeID on the newgen account and update the metadata.
   //Returns null even though it exists in the dashboard

   String deschargeID = result.Transfer.DestinationPayment;

   var chargeService = new StripeChargeService(newgenSecretKey);
   StripeCharge charge = chargeService.Get(deschargeID);
   charge.Metadata = myDict;
   Response.Redirect("PgeCustSuccess.aspx?OrderID=" + OrderID);

  }
 } catch (StripeException stripeException) {

  Debug.WriteLine(stripeException.Message);
  stripe.Text = stripeException.Message;


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object)'s [`transfer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-transfer) attribute is not [expanded](https://stripe.com/docs/api#expanding_objects) by default, meaning it's just a string with the ID of the [transfer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#transfer_object) (`"tr_..."`), not a full transfer object.

According to Stripe.net's [documentation](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#expandable-properties), you can expand the `transfer` attribute by adding this line:

```
service.ExpandTransfer = True
```

before sending the charge creation request.

Comment: Thank you @Ywain. that was easy. You are a life saver.

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath Glad I could help! :)