# Updating a charge in Stripe

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe-connect

I am using stripe.net for making payments in asp.net. I ran into a problem. I couldn’t update the metadata of the charge retrieved, although I was able to retrieve the charge from stripe as per the documentation on stripe.net. However updating a charge is not mentioned in the documentation. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code that I am using

```
var chargeService = new StripeChargeService(newgenSecretKey);

//successfully retrieves the charge
StripeCharge charge = chargeService.Get("py_1AXfkAJsBBkng4KEnulfiR7I");

//Metadata is not getting updated
charge.Metadata = myDict;
```

The following code does not update the Meta Data in the dashboard. 
Apart from this, there is another option of `StripeChargeUpdateOptions` but I am not sure how this was intended to work. There is not documentation in github as well. Unlike the `StripeChargeService` which take in the stripe secret key as argument,`StripeChargeUpdateOptions` does not take any. I tried using this without any luck. But I think this is what I have to use because for a charge you can only update 4 parameters including metadata and `StripeChargeUpdateOptions` has only those. I was wondering if anyone out there could help me with this.

The following code is what I tried

```
var chargeServiceupdate = new StripeChargeUpdateOptions();
chargeServiceupdate.Metadata = myDict;
```

PS : MyDict is a dictionary and I tried using it when creating a charge. Meta data is succesfully being set. Cannot do the same when I retrieve a charge and try to set it.

Comment: Does Stripe document anywhere that they provide this functionality?

Comment: Yes. It can be done via api calls. I am using Stripe.Net library. However, How to update a charge is not documented

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_charge

Comment: https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/blob/96cdbaffa5609ab6f8c4925342247c5a8be6f0ac/src/Stripe.net/Services/Charges/StripeChargeService.cs shows an `Update` method. Have you tried calling that?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code you tried that called the `Update` method? And also specify what you mean by 'did not work'.

Comment: I mentioned it in the last part of my question. Here is what i tried var chargeServiceupdate = new StripeChargeUpdateOptions();
chargeServiceupdate.Metadata = myDict;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper has a class called [StripeChargeService](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/blob/96cdbaffa5609ab6f8c4925342247c5a8be6f0ac/src/Stripe.net/Services/Charges/StripeChargeService.cs) with an `Update` method.

You need to call **that** method.

*If you are missing that method then you are likely running an old version of the library (see https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/issues/412) and need to upgrade to the latest version.*

[Updating MetaData on Connected account fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711541/updating-metadata-on-connected-account-fails) may also be of assistance.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I am not sure why they don't include all this in the documentation. I got confused because there was a StripeChargeUpdateOptions without a constructor. Wonder what the purpose of that is !!